# Make:migration command in symfony is running for long without working

Tags: file, symfony, debugging, orm, migration

I face an error since a long time that force me to make changes directly in phpmyadmin.
After changing my entities, when I run

> php bin/concole make:migration

the command run for the infinty without displaying any error and creating a migration file.

Please I hope someone can tell me what is it due for.

Comment: Show us more details. Make your command Verbose by adding `-vvv` at this end of your command like `php bin/concole make:migration -vvv`

Answer (score 0):

The `make:migration` creates a .php file in the `src/Migrations` directory. If you have many changes this process maybe take more time, so try it again with only one entity in your system. If you don't have this directory create it and be sure to give permissions to write (maybe your system don't have it). Finally try to press enter in your command , some tools waits for input to continue (like PowerShell).